# How to sort string array in java?

Tags: sorting

I have customized string array 
for an example:

```
String[] myArr = {"Zen", "Maruthi","Swift", "Audi"};
```

I have a tool which will generate array like

```
String[] output = getCars();//returns {"Swift", "Audi", "Zen", "Maruthi"}

// it should return same as myArr...means {"Zen", "Maruthi","Swift", "Audi"}
```

I want to sort **output** arrays to **myArr**; i am sorting using for loop with comparison of **myArr;**

So is there any other method to sort customised array?plz help me

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

No need to sort here. Just add similar string into the `list` as per element(s) sequence in `myArr` array.

```
List<String> items=new ArrayList<String>();
for(String item:myArr)
 {
  for(String outputItem:output)
   {
     if(item.equals(outputItem))
        items.add(outputItem);
     }                    
   } 
 for(String s:items)
     System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: This will return ascending order...I know this method...But i am asking ,the order should be same myArr(custom)...how to get output same as myArr?